# Plotting geom_bar and geom_point together?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data=data.frame(x=rep(0:9, each=2))

ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(x))) + geom_bar(alpha=0.5) + 
    geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0:10, y=2), aes(x=factor(x), y=y), alpha=0.5) 

ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(x))) + geom_bar(alpha=0.5) + 
    geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0:10, y=2), aes(x=factor(x), y=y), alpha=0.5) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=0:10)
```

Also, do I have to `factor` given `x` is `integer` so it is discrete already?
[image] 
Wrong order
[image]
Wrong x axis label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) + geom_bar(alpha=0.5) + scale_x_discrete(limits=0:10) + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0:10, y=2), aes(x=x, y=y), alpha=0.5)
```

You can force a discrete scale to get what you want.  It is odd how when you mix geom_point() and geom_bar() ggplot starts ordering things in unexpected ways.

[image]

Comment: still, it is not perfect since there are -1 remaining in the axis