# Overlaying geom_points on geom_bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on creating a graph, where the length of the geom_bar represents the time each person spent in an activity. Now, I want to layer in instances within the activity (using geom_point) over the bar.

I read another question [Plotting geom_bar and geom_point together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884402/plotting-geom-bar-and-geom-point-together) that got me as far as I am.

```
library(ggplot2)
plot1<-ggplot(tt,aes(x=Actor,y=Task.Time))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab("")+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0:940,y=0), aes(x=2,y=941))+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0:940,y=0), aes(x=1,y=941))
```

[image]

Note that the max time spent was 940 seconds. I need the instances (geom-points) to layover the bars. The points where they exist now are incorrect. The y values for Renee are stored in r$Qualifier..Time and Gia in g$Qualifier..Time. I would also like to set the shape and color of the points to qualifier type, stored in g$Qualifier and r$Qualifier, respectively. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, preferrably via `dput()`?

Comment: Hi. I just did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data in the OP a few minutes ago:

```
ggplot(tt,aes(x=Actor,y=Task.Time))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab("")+
  geom_point(data=r, aes(x=2,y=Qualifier..Time)) +
  geom_point(data=g, aes(x=1,y=Qualifier..Time))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.  Yes. Sorry. I had a typo that I fixed (I forgot to subtract start time). Regardless, this works and I can make the adjustments. Thank you so much!